# How are parameters passed through HttpClient in .NET Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I am very, very new to the entire idea of `REST` and calling an API from http in general, but for a project I am working on, it has become necessary.

I am using `ASP.NET Core`, so I've been trying to find a REST library. When I was using standard `.NET`, I could use `RestSharp`, but the community made `RestSharp.Core` is pretty out of date and has many incompatibilities with newer versions of `.NET Standard 1.6+`.

To that end, I've explored other options, but my inexperience just makes it frustrating. Inevitably, I'm thinking it is best if I just use the built in `HttpClient` class. But I'm not sure how to do that for this exact scenario. I'm having a very hard time understanding how to give the parameters to the request, and what I'm specifically looking for in the return value.

My needs are pretty simple;

1. create a connection to `$url`
2. specify that it is a `POST` operation.
3. pass an existing `JSON` object to the server when making the request.
4. get `JSON` data back.

My code, using old `RestSharp.Core`, looks a bit like this - obviously keys and such omitted for privacy.

```
public async Task<string> OpenApiAsync() {
    var token = await Task.Run(async () => {
        var httpClient = new RestClient("https://[OMITTED].auth0.com/oauth/token");
        var httpRequest = new RestRequest() {
            Serializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.JsonSerializer(),
            Method = Method.POST
        };

        httpRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httpRequest.AddJsonBody(new {
            client_id = _settings.Value.ClientId,
            client_secret = _settings.Value.ClientSecret,
            audience = _settings.Value.Audience,
            grant_type = _settings.Value.GrantType
        });

        var httpResponse = await httpClient.Execute(httpRequest);
        var deserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
        return deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(httpResponse);
    });

    return token["access_token"]);
}
```

The `_settings` object is injected with `IOptions<Auth0Settings>`, which has this shape and general data.

```
"authentication": {
    "Domain": "[auth0-domain]",
    "Audience": "https://[OMITTED].auth0.com/api/v2/",
    "ClientId": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP....",
    "ClientSecret": "A22u5hgbnwifhwihfwi20u559f...",
    "CallbackUrl": "http://localhost:5000/signin-auth0",
    "GrantType": "client_credentials"
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how this could be ported to the native `HttpClient` that is in `.NET Standard 1.6+`? I specifically need one that is compatible with `netstandard1.6` and `netcoreapp1.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a very good http client and should be used in .NET core moving forward :)

```
private static async Task<string> OpenApiAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json");
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YOUR_BODY);
        var result = await client.PostAsync("https://[OMITTED].auth0.com/oauth/token", new StringContent(body , Encoding.UTF8));
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return deserialized["access_token"];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This cleared a lot up, and it allowed me to drop a dependency on a pretty heavy and unstable package!

Comment: @Ciel one nice thing about ```HttpClient``` is that it's thread-safe. So generally best practice is to use one ```HttpClient``` per remote server :)